# How to always run a main file in Spyder Project

Tags: python, anaconda, project, spyder

I'm developing a python project with multiple files, it's annoying that I have to select the file where main is described and called before click run because if not Spyder3(Anaconda) runs the current selected file.

How can I do to run my project from main() in mainPrjPy.py independent if the file is opened and selected?

Thanks

EDIT: I want to explain that I'm using Spyder as Matlab substitute for Physics and math simulation for electronic design, this project would grow with different people generating different algorithms and data processor.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a practical way to set this up, or why it's an issue. Just keep the file with your overall entry point open as a tab and switch to it before clicking run. The default behaviour seems massively more practical to me.

Comment: Yhea..., you are right, it's not an issue, but if I'm working in a file it's 3 or 4 levels away from the main, I change code and press F5 and... shit I didn't select the main tab. I'm used to program, embedded devices or FPGAs where you run the project not a file(script). My conclusion of this is that spyder is not meant to do projects only little scripts, because I want to run the project no one of its  files. But hope there is a way to do that.

Comment: "My conclusion of this is that spyder is not meant to do projects only little scripts" tell that to the 40,000 line project I've just built in Spyder :) Pycharm may be better suited to your desired behaviour (though I haven't used it much). But some of that assertion may be correct - Spyder is geared more to scientific computing due to the iPython console. An IDE more suited to large-scale applications will probably not have such features easily accessible.

Comment: hehehe, yes I get to spyder because I didn't want to use matlab or octave and most important python is compatible with ROOT(CERN) via pyROOT. Maybe with time I found this way of working very natural and would eat the sentence you quoted me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't have this functionality at the moment (November 2019), sorry.

Comment: Thanks!! would be part of anaconda?

Comment: Yes, it will be part of it as soon as release it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba , is this still scheduled for version 4?  I'm not able to find it in beta.

Comment: No, we couldn't add it to Spyder 4, sorry.

Comment: Was looking for this too; would be a big time saver and really surprising not to find it. A project preference for the path or a key sequence such as Alt-F5 to run the last file that had been run with F5 would suffice. The latter has the upside of no gui or project save/load implications, just a new default key sequence, action, and somewhere to remember the last path.

Comment: We're planning to add this functionality for Spyder 5, to be released in 2021.

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to do this:
Use "Run Again Last file" Shortcut key F6 on windows.

It's working fine on Spyder 3.3.6

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. That's a shame a run configuration is not available per project in the IDE (3 years later!), and there is no equivalent to this bypass for debug.

Comment: I no longer use spyder, but happy to hear there is a work around that works similar to expected.

Comment: Which IDE is better than Spyder?