# How do I always debug a main file in Spyder 5.0.0?

Tags: debugging, spyder

I found this question with reference to running a main file:
[How to always run a main file in Spyder Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943962/how-to-always-run-a-main-file-in-spyder-project)

Is there any way to always debug starting on a main file selected by the developer in Spyder 5.0.0? Having to select the tab of the main file every time before debugging is not really convenient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's not possible at the moment, sorry.